# symfony vichupload cashe:clear Expected to find class "App\Message\EventSubscriber"

Tags: class, symfony, deployment, vichuploaderbundle

After a redeployment of a website that I created with symfony 5, I have an error when I do a clear cache:
Expected to find class "App\Message\EventSubscriber" in file "/home/nduqhkrs/cineconde/src/Message/EventSubscriber.php" while importing services from resource "../src/", but it was not found! Check the namespace prefix used with the resource.

I tried to import class App\Message\EventSubscriber, but still not work.here is the EventSubscriber file :

```
    namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use App\Message\RemoveProductImageMessage;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Messenger\MessageBusInterface;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Event\Event;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Event\Events;

class RemoveFileEventSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface

{

private $messageBus;

public function __construct(MessageBusInterface $messageBus)
{
    $this->messageBus = $messageBus;
}

public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
{
    return [
        Events::PRE_REMOVE => ['onPreRemove'],
    ];
}

public function onPreRemove(Event $event): void
{
    $mapping = $event->getMapping();
    $mappingName = $mapping->getMappingName();

    if ('product_image' === $mappingName) {
        $this->dispatch(RemoveProductImageMessage::class, $event);
    }
}

private function dispatch(string $messageClass, Event $event): void
{
    $event->cancel();

    $object = $event->getObject();

    $mapping = $event->getMapping();
    $filename = $mapping->getFileName($object);

    $message = new $messageClass($filename);
    $this->messageBus->dispatch($message);
}
}
```

I tried to dump the autoloader but I still have the problem. The class is not present in the services.yaml :

```
parameters:
locale: 'en'

services:
# default configuration for services in *this* file
_defaults:
autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your            services.
autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands,  event subscribers, etc.

# makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
# this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
App\:
resource: '../src/*'

exclude:
    - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
    - '../src/Entity/'
    - '../src/Kernel.php'
    - '../src/Tests/'

# controllers are imported separately to make sure services can be injected
# as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller class


App\Controller\:
resource: '../src/Controller/'
tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

# add more service definitions when explicit configuration is needed
# please note that last definitions always *replace* previous ones
```

Thanks for helping...

Comment: Show your services.yaml. Have you declared the service?

Comment: Note: For such purposes, it is better to use Doctrine Entity Listeners, instead of Doctrine Lifecycle Subscribers. Since Doctrine Entity Listeners are considered to be more performant due to the fact that instances are only started when the events in the desired entity are actually fired.  Here is a well documented article on the subject https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/events.html

Answer (score 0):

You are showing the code to a class that isn't the problem. The problem in the error is in `App\Message\EventSubscriber`. Symfony cannot find that class. You are showing code for `App\EventSubscriber\RemoveFileEventSubscriber` which is the wrong place to look.

There are several reasons this can happen.

1. Sometimes this is a result of not clearing the cache. Since the error is occurring when you do this, probably this is not the reason in this case.
2. Did you dump the composer autoloader again? Depending on how you've set up your composer, you may need to dump the autoloader again: `composer dumpautoload`
3. Is autoloading set up properly for that directory? See your `config/services.yaml` file. Under the `services:App\:` key be sure the file falls into the `resource` category and is not under the `exclude` directories.
4. Is the class actually present? Is the file properly named and properly located by namespace? check for typos, missed capitalization, etc.

Comment: I tried to dump the autoloader but I still have the problem. The class is not present in the services.yaml

Comment: perhaps you could show the class that is causing the problem instead of some other irrelevant class?

Comment: I don't have any class App\Message\EventSubscriber but a file .../src/Message/EventSubscriber.php

Comment: if you have this file `src/Message/EventSubscriber.php` then you _should_ have this class `App\Message\EventSubscriber`. If you don't then this is the root of the problem. :-) The class `App\Message\EventSubscriber` must live in the file `src/Message/EventSubscriber.php`. This is how autoloading works.

Comment: I changed the name class App\Message\EventSubscriber but I still have the message : Expected to find class "App\Message\EventSubscriber" in file "../s   
  rc/Message/EventSubscriber.php" while importing services from resource "../src/*", but i   
  t was not found! Check the namespace prefix used with the resource.

Comment: It says: "Check the namespace prefix used with the resource." And so... did you? Think about what that message is trying to tell you. Do you know what a namespace is? You need to learn about how this works to better understand the solution. Your namespace above is `namespace App\EventSubscriber;` but you have placed the file in `../src/Message/EventSubscriber.php` Do you see the conflict? The namespace structure and the directory structure must _match_. This is the foundation of PSR-0 namespacing.

Comment: I have to thank you for reminding me of this. It was the solution to my problem.